# Build an Android app written in Kotlin using Buck build system

Tags: android, kotlin, buck

Buck supports building Java-based Android projects. There is a project https://github.com/zserge/buckbone that adds "experimental" Kotlin support but it's far from being usable.

Is there a way to build an Android app written in Kotlin using Buck build system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't currently a great way to do this, but [zserge](https://github.com/zserge) has been the one dabbling in it (check out some of the issues they've filed in Buck).  [scrawlings](https://github.com/scrawlings) actually recently did a [refactor](https://github.com/facebook/buck/commit/4c4a24a991ad94ae8a8f92c3d1df57513773f217) of Buck's Java code to make [support for Groovy](https://github.com/facebook/buck/pull/439) easier, which would make it a lot easier to fully support Kotlin too.  The core team isn't likely to work on that, but we'd certainly take a PR for it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye on this [Uber open-source library](https://github.com/uber/okbuck) called OkBuck that lets you compile Java and Kotlin code using the Buck build system. This is what they are currently using for all their apps.

**Note:** You will have to give it a try to see if they support everything you need, I'm not fully aware of the status of the compatibility with Kotlin, but I can confirm they are already building Kotlin apps with it.

Comment: worth to try OkBuck build system